# Docker Compose in BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following BitBucket Pipeline

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
        caches:
              - dotnetcore
        script:
              - REPORTS_PATH=./test-reports/build_${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
              - dotnet restore
              - dotnet build --no-restore --configuration Release
    - step:
        name: API Test
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
        trigger: manual
        services:
          - customdocker
        script:
          - docker-compose -f docker-compose-api-tests.yml build
          - docker-compose -f docker-compose-api-tests.yml up
definitions:
    services:
        customdocker:
            image: docker/compose:1.28.5
```

I am trying to run docker-compose inside the pipeline. I get the following error:

> - docker-compose -f docker-compose-api-tests.yml build bash: docker-compose: command not found

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
        caches:
              - dotnetcore
        script:
              - REPORTS_PATH=./test-reports/build_${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
              - dotnet restore
              - dotnet build --no-restore --configuration Release
    - step:
        name: Postman Tests
        image: python:3.8.1
        services:
            - docker
        caches:
            - docker
            - pip
        script:
            - pip install docker-compose
            - docker network create dockernet
            - docker-compose -f docker-compose-api-tests.yml build
            - docker-compose -f docker-compose-api-tests.yml up --exit-code-from postman
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a tool that is not present in the default image used by pipelines. You have two ways to resolve that:

1. install the tool during your build (you did that in your own answer)
2. use a different build image that already contains your required tool

See [bitbuckets documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-docker-images-as-build-environments/).

Bitbucket advises users to explicitly pick a build image because the defaults are pretty old and rarely updated. for your usecase the [docker-compose image](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose) might be good.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of default Atlassian image contains docker-compose

```
script:
  - /usr/local/bin/docker-compose version
```

output:

```
+ /usr/local/bin/docker-compose version
Docker Compose version v2.15.1
```